# Difference between MEF and Refrenced dll

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism, mef, silverlight-5.0

I am working on a silverlight project and I am using MEF to download xap file of other silverlight project and use its pages and functions in my main Project.

I can do the same thing using referencing dll of that project into my main project.

So I want to know what is the difference between using MEF to reusing components and Simply Adding Reference to the DLL of another project in current project? I mean that we also add reference to the project we import in our current project. Then how it is different from conventional form of component use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to separate MEF and PRISM (since you used it in your tags).

MEF is primarily used to provide [inversion of control (IoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). It makes it easy to manage dependencies your viewmodels and other classes to separate concerns and improve testability (amongst other benefits).

PRISM however is primarily designed for the following scenario: You don't know, what view goes into a specific container at **compile time**, and want ViewA for CustomerA, ViewB for CustomerB and so on. PRISM helps you to losely couple your regions and views in a way, so that the application can decide at **runtime**, what view will be displayed. Another scenario, is that administrators get one view, other users another etc. PRISM also has other features (like the event aggregator), but I'd say the former is the most important one.

Now, I'd say MEF is never a bad thing to use for a bigger project. But I'd only use PRISM, if you really need the functionality it provides, since it can be very limiting. If you don't, simply add the references as you explained and let MEF know about those assemblies with the *AssemblyCatalog*.

So for MEF, I'd suggest you learn about Depdendency Injection and IoC. I found [this blogpost by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) quite good. As for PRISM, get familiar with what it does, and decide if you really need it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply... But I am asking difference between MEF and Referencing dll.Can u plz help me to find difference between them?

Comment: With referencing, you make tight coupling, with MEF you make loose coupling. If you read up on dependency injection, this explanation will be very clear :>

Answer (score 0):

Let me complement Lue's answer on the difference between MEF and referencing dlls a bit:

The two things are orthogonal activities, meaning that if you reference a dll directly you might still want to use MEF to detect the types in it - and vice versa you might grab a specific type in a dll you dynamically loaded directly (without MEF).

MEF basically finds types in dlls according to certain criteria and has a bit of convenience stuff in it to automatically populate properties and collections with such types. It can be used to make a system more decoupled and thus more maintainable. For example, a video editing software may look for all types implementing a certain interface in all known dlls to use as filters. Whether you include the filters directly as a dll or let the user download them on demand: In both cases your application becomes slightly cleaner by using MEF, since there is no hard-coded list of filters anywhere. Still, in the presence of dynamic library loading MEF is especially useful.